# Mysql Find Duplicates from two different tables

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I have one **contacts table** with following fields :

```
id,
first_name,
last_name,
```

Also one more **email_contacts table** with following fields:

```
id,
email_address_id,
bean_id,
```

`bean_id` is the unique id from `contacts table` and `email_address_id` is unique id from other third **email table**.

I want to find duplicates from contacts table along with their respective emails.

Comment: What is a doublet in your case? first and last name?

Comment: Actually when adding contacts from application it adds firstname,lastname in contacts table.And adds email & contact id(my case bean_id) in email_contacts table.I want to fetch firstname,lastname and email_id having duplicates.

Comment: Is the email_id a number of the actual email address?

Comment: Yes it's an unique id of the actual email address in email_address table.This table have 2 main columns one unique id as id and other email.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm not seeing the whole problem, but it would appear that `contacts.id` is a primary key, and `email_contacts.bean_id` is a foreign key. 
If that's the case, then SELECT `contacts.first_name`, `contacts.last_name`, and `email_contacts.email_id` with a JOIN on `contacts.id` = `email_contacts.bean_id`.
Let me know if this answer is in the right direction, and then we can address the question of duplicate records.